# How to avoid page refresh after button click event in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

This is the following code the page refreshes as soon as the btninsert click event is completed i want to stop the page refresh after the btninsert is click

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

    <ContentTemplate>


        <div style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 20px;"><span><strong style="font-size: large;">Edit User</strong></span></div>
        <div>
            <span style="float: left; width: 50%;">&nbsp;</span> <span style="float: left; width: 50%;">
                <span style="width: 100%; float: left; text-align: right;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="-"></asp:Label></span>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div style="width: 100%; float: left;">
            <hr />
        </div>


        <div style="width: 816px; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 20px; height: 463px;">

            <div style="width: 100%; float: left; padding-top: 15px; height: 257px; margin-left: 0px;">
                <span class="Divide">
                    <span class="simDivide1">FullName</span>
                    <span class="simDivide">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtfullname" runat="server" Width="180px">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </span>


                </span>
                <span class="Divide">
                    <span class="simDivide1"></span>
                    <span class="simDivide"></span>
                </span>


                <span class="Divide">
                    <span class="simDivide1">Username</span>
                    <span class="simDivide">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtusername" runat="server" Width="180px">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </span>
                </span>

                <span class="Divide">
                    <span class="simDivide1"></span>
                    <span class="simDivide"></span>
                </span>

                <span class="Divide">
                    <span class="simDivide1">Password</span>
                    <span class="simDivide">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" runat="server" Width="180px">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </span>
                </span>

                <span class="Divide">
                    <span class="simDivide1"></span>
                    <span class="simDivide"></span>
                </span>


                <span class="Divide">
                    <span class="simDivide1">Mobile No
                    </span>
                    &nbsp;<span class="simDivide"><asp:TextBox ID="txtmobileno" runat="server" Width="180px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    </span>
                </span>

                <span class="Divide">

                    <span class="simDivide"></span>
                </span>


                <span class="Divide">
                    <span class="simDivide1">Role
                    </span>
                    &nbsp;<span class="simDivide"><asp:TextBox ID="txtrole" runat="server" Width="180px">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    </span>
                </span>



                <script src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

                <script language="javascript">

                    function done() {
                        var list = document.getElementById("tid");
                        list.removeChild(list.lastChild);


                    }


                    function changecourse(e) {

                        var change = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
                        var i = 1;

                        mNewObj = document.createElement('div');
                        mNewObj.id = "BOX" + i;
                        mNewObj.style.visibility = "show";
                        mNewObj.innerHTML = change + "&nbsp<a href='#' style='text-decoration: none; color:red' onClick='done()'> x </a> ";


                        document.getElementById("tid").appendChild(mNewObj);
                        i++
                        var a = document.getElementById('mytext').selectedIndex;
                        document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Hidden1").value = a;
                        //document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btninsert").click();

                        deleted();




                    }

                    function yes() {

                        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btninsert").click();

                    }


                    //function insert() {

                    //    $.ajax({
                    //        type: "POST",
                    //        url: "Edituser.aspx.cs/insert",

                    //        success: function () { alert('success'); },
                    //        error: function () { alert('error'); }

                    //    });


                    //}


                    function cancel() {

                        var select = document.getElementById('mytext');
                        select.remove(select.selectedIndex);
                    }


                    function deleted() {

                        document.getElementById("mytext").style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById("Button1").style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById("tid").style.display = 'inline';
                        document.getElementById("mylink").style.display = 'inline';
                    }



                    function showdiv() {

                        document.getElementById("mylink").style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById("mytext").style.display = 'inline';
                        document.getElementById("Button1").style.display = 'inline';


                    }


                </script>



            <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Style="margin-left: 5px" Text="Edit" Width="39px" />
            <br>
            <br>

            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
           &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<div id="tid" >
                               </div>
            <div id="di">

                <a id="mylink" onclick="showdiv()">Add Depot</a>

                <select id='mytext' name='mytext' style="display: none">
                    <option>--Select--</option>
                    <option>Mumbai</option>
                    <option>Delhi</option>
                    <option>Banglore</option>
                    <option>Ahmedabad</option>
                </select>
               <input type="button" id="Button1" style="display: none" onclick=" changecourse(); yes(); cancel(); return false;" value="add" />
                </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btninsert" runat="server"  Style="display: none" OnClick="btninsert_Click" Text="Insert" ValidationGroup="C" />

                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
             </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this is Edit.aspx.cs in which i have method

```
    protected void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = Hidden1.Value;
        string UserId = Convert.ToString(Session["LoginId"]);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserDepot (UserId,DepotId)" +
            "VALUES ('" + UserId + "','" + a + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();


    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to stop page refresh???
If you do that, then ur SqlCommand won't get executed...
Are you trying to maintain the values of the page or what?

Answer (score 24):

Add `OnClientClick="return false;"`  ,

```
<asp:button ID="btninsert" runat="server" text="Button" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

or in the CodeBehind:

```
 btninsert.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
```

Comment: It will not call the function as well.

Comment: This works.Should be marked as solution. However, for reducing confusion the example  should include the function too:

<asp:button ID="btninsert" runat="server" text="Button" onClick = "{Your function goes here}" OnClientClick="return false;" />

Comment: @NegativeFeedbackLoop It doesn't matter if the `onClick` function is included; as Zeeshan's comment says, having `return false` in the OnClientClick attribute will prevent that function from being called, so it's the same as not having the function in there at all.

Answer (score 10):

if you have some codes in your Page_Load method and you don't want that those execute after button click use  if(!IsPostBack)  on Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       // put codes here
    }
}
```

asp:Button is a server control and for send request to server and get response need page refresh. You can use JQuery and Ajax to prevent full Page refresh

Answer (score 9):

As you are using `asp:Button` which is a server control, post back will happen to avoid that go for `html` button,

```
asp:Button .... />
```

Type to

```
input type="button" .... />
```

Answer (score 5):

Page got refreshed when a trip to server is made, and server controls like **Button** has a property **AutoPostback = true** by default which means whenever they are clicked a trip to server will be made.
Set **AutoPostback = false** for insert button, and this will do the trick for you.

Comment: Frankly button with AutoPostback = false is frozen i.e. it cannot do anything unless u decide to send an Ajax call inside its click event. Please check that your button is inside another  server control? If it is then that control will be responsible for page refreshes.

Answer (score 3):

Set `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true"` in the page declaration:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" Title="Home" %>
```

Comment: OP stated they wanted to stop page refresh, not to remember the scroll position.  Why is this being suggested?

Comment: This does not address the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a button doing a page refresh before doing the actual button_click event (so the button had to be clicked twice).
This behavior happened after a server.transfer-command (server.transfer("testpage.aspx").

In this case, the solution was to replace the server.transfer-command with response-redirect (response.redirect("testpage.aspx").

For details on the differences between the two commands, see 
[Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect)